# Is there a way to traverse through the DAG in TensorFlow with python?

Tags: tensorflow, graph

For the task at hand I want to trace all operations that follow BatchNormalization layer until I find a multiplication with trainable variable (weight) to push covariance into the weight.

In order to do that I would ideally need next things:

- Given operation *op1* get list of operations that depend on *op1*
- Given operation *op2* get list of operands (operations op2 depends
  on)

I believe this can be done by analyzing graph.meta saved as .txt but I still hope some of this functionality is directly exposed in python.

Comment: I don't know any Pythonic way to do that but have you tried TensorBoard (GRAPH page)?

Comment: sure, but my idea is to automate this lookup process.

Comment: Any luck? You can do this in C++ see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph_main.cc#L124